# Possible memory leak in lodash.js during _.bind

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, underscore.js, bind, lodash

I've created a very simple empty web-page with the only link to a `lodash` library.
Then (directly in Chrome console) I create a simple class:

```
window.class = function() {
    this.bound = _.bind(this.toBind, this);
}
window.class.prototype.toBind = function() {
    this.value = 'value';
}
```

Instances of this class will have only 1 property `value` and 2 methods: `toBind` and `bound` (which is a bound version of `toBind`).
Then I take a heap snapshot via Chrome dev toolbar - Snapshot1 - this is the initial state of heap.
Then I create an instance of `class` and delete it:

```
window.obj = new window.class()
window.obj = null;
delete window.obj;
```

And finally I take another heap snapshot.
I expect that the `obj` instance is no longer alive as there are no more references to it (the only one was window.obj but in the last step it was removed). But the comparison of two heap snapshot shows that the object is still alive seems that lodash itself references to it (tested in Chrome 34.0.1847.131).

[image]

Can someone explain if this is a real memory leak inside lodash? Or is there any secret meaning of such behavior?
**Note:** the native [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) works correctly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in lodash. Will be fixed in version next to 2.4.1.
Bugtracking [ticket](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/554). Fixed in [commit](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commit/3936d4f0307de24730e4060ff3f8ef0271572b7c).